# C# Selenium Angular Can't Select DropDown Option

Tags: c#, angular, selenium-webdriver, hidden

I am trying to select a dropdown option.  Listed below is my code:

```
IWebElement webElement7 = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='k-list-scroller']//ul[@class='k-list k-reset']//li[@class='k-item' and @data-offset-index='1']")));
webElement7.Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="k-animation-container" style="width: 306px; height: 115px; margin-left: -10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px; display: none; box-sizing: content-box; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 202px; z-index: 10002; left: 1427.25px;"><div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="GenderID-list" data-role="popup" style="position: absolute; font-size: 14px; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px; width: 300.25px; height: auto; display: none; transform: translateY(-115px);"><div class="k-list-optionlabel k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="e21a4b75-ad22-40c8-a3d5-dbbcd9a1f8ea">--Select--</div><div class="k-group-header" style="display:none"></div><div class="k-list-scroller" unselectable="on" style="height: auto;"><ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="GenderID_listbox" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox"><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="0">Female</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Male</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">Unknown</li></ul></div></div></div>
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="GenderID-list" data-role="popup" style="position: absolute; font-size: 14px; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-stretch: 100%; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px; width: 300.25px; height: auto; display: none; transform: translateY(-115px);"><div class="k-list-optionlabel k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="e21a4b75-ad22-40c8-a3d5-dbbcd9a1f8ea">--Select--</div><div class="k-group-header" style="display:none"></div><div class="k-list-scroller" unselectable="on" style="height: auto;"><ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="GenderID_listbox" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox"><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="0">Female</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Male</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">Unknown</li></ul></div></div>
<div class="k-list-optionlabel k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="e21a4b75-ad22-40c8-a3d5-dbbcd9a1f8ea">--Select--</div>
<div class="k-group-header" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="k-list-scroller" unselectable="on" style="height: auto;"><ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="GenderID_listbox" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox"><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="0">Female</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Male</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">Unknown</li></ul></div>
<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="GenderID_listbox" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox"><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="0">Female</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Male</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">Unknown</li></ul>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="0">Female</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Male</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">Unknown</li>
```

Listed below is my error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
```

Comment: Update the question with the error trace log

Comment: You aren't dealing with an actual dropdown, it's a faked one with nested HTML. My guess is that you aren't clicking the dropdown to open it and expose the options inside before clicking the desired option. You may need a wait after the click to open and before the option click.